# How to access a value of a case class without explicitly passing the class arguments

Tags: scala

I have a case class that extends 2 traits. Is there a way to access the value of a case class without passing all arguments?

When I create object of class and access value schemaName, it asks for the case class arguments like name and age.

```
val schemaObject = new Customer()
val schema = schemaObject.schemaName
```

I learned about passing the case class as self but not sure how to implement it. Is ther any other way to do this?

```
case class Customer(name: String,age: Int) extends traintA with traitB {
  val schemaName: Schema = ??

  def buildKafkaStruct(): Struct = {
    val structRecord = new Struct(schemaName)
      .put("name", this.name)
      .put("age", this.age

    structRecord
  }
}

traitA{
     val name: String  

}

traitB{
      val schemaName: Schema
  def buildKafkaStruct(): Struct  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking how to access the field `schemaName` without instantiating a `Customer`?

If so, as is, it's not possible.

However, if `schemaName` is a constant value, it would make more sense to be in the companion object. This way it would be accessible without an instance of `Customer`:

```scala
object Customer {

  val schemaName = ???

}

// Access it from somewhere else
val schema = Customer.schemaName

// Including in case class instances if you need it for compliance with the trait
case class Customer(...) {

  override val schemaName = Customer.schemaName

}
```

Comment: Is there  a way to do it without a companion object?

Comment: @reply Is there a way to do it without a companion object? Can self be leveraged? bascially pass customer class itself which has all argumets

Comment: @SakshiTrivedi if you already have an instance of customer class, you don't need to pass it anywhere, just do `customer.schemaName`

Comment: @SakshiTrivedi, I don't understand. `this` (self) can be used inside the case class definition but not outside.